# HTTPPOST to aspx file

Tags: android, asp.net, http-post

I want to post to this url

http://abc.com/Registration.aspx?MailID=PickUp&UserName=as&PickUpTime=19191919&Notes=bla&DeviceId=0000

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://abc.com/Davis/Registration.aspx");
    httppost.setHeader("MailID","MailID=PickUp");
    try {
        // Add your data

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MailID","PickUp"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName","as"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PickUpTime",date));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Notes",note));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceId",deviceID));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Also how can I know what url I am passing . How can I log it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure MailID should be in the header? From the wording of the question, it looks as if all values are in the query string (in the URL past the ? mark). But then why would you need POST for that; a GET would be sufficient.

And passing data, like MailID, in headers is almost unheard of. Querystring and POST form, those are the most popular places.

So first figure out the interface of the server page. Does it expect GET or POST (or either)? Then place the fields into the right place - either into the URL (by string concatenation), or into the entity.

Oh, and the URL you're passing is `http://abc.com/Davis/Registration.aspx`. Neither `setHeader()` nor `setEntity()` modifies the URL per se.